# How to fix the RuntimeException in genuitec's TypeScript Editor for eclipse oxygen?

Tags: eclipse, angular, typescript, eclipse-plugin

I have installed a fresh eclipse oxygen and the Angular IDE from genuitec.
The second day I opened my project and opened a *.ts File, I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The node process has crashed.
Last 4 lines of error console output:
Bridge type: classifier
Running with TS version:2.3.4
Initializing endpoint classifier in version 2.3.4
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: src\node_file.cc:557: Assertion `args[0]->IsString()' failed.


    at com.genuitec.eclipse.typescript.services.internal.Bridge.call(Bridge.java:162)

    at com.genuitec.eclipse.typescript.services.classifier.Classifier.getClassificationsForLines(Classifier.java:62)

    at com.genuitec.eclipse.typescript.text.reconciler.PresentationReconciler.classifyLines(PresentationReconciler.java:264)

    at com.genuitec.eclipse.typescript.text.reconciler.PresentationReconciler.createPresentation(PresentationReconciler.java:232)

    at com.genuitec.eclipse.typescript.text.reconciler.PresentationReconciler.processEvent(PresentationReconciler.java:130)
```

how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall *Angular IDE* from Genuitec and use the ***[Angular Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular2-eclipse)*** plug-in instead.

The closed source *Angular IDE* does load-time weaving to patch Java bytecode of the Eclipse platform and other plug-ins (for legal reasons; to not have to publish their changes). In contrast of using a public API, load-time weaving patches are difficult to maintain and errors are difficult to locate and to fix.

Comment: AngularJS Eclipse is for Angular1, please install https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular2-eclipse for Angular2

Comment: @Angelo Thx for your comment. I changed the answer accordingly. Please feel free to edit my answer. As _Angular Eclipse_ author you know better than I do.

Comment: Genuitec uses AngularJS Eclipse but their Angular IDE is not based on Angular2 Eclipse. Please remove the "original"

Comment: @Angelo Thx for the adjustment. Whether AngularJS or Angular2, for me your plug-in is the original. ;-)

Comment: Thx for the help. I have to add, that I had to reinstall eclipse oxygen because when I opened *.ts files with "Angular2 Eclipse", an error dialog opened with several NullPointerExceptions. After reinstall the errors were gone.

Comment: @artgrohe please create an issue at https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/issues if you can reproduce the problem or if you have in the error log stacktrace of your NPE. Thanks!

Comment: Angelo, Angular IDE provides Angular (formerly known as Angular 2) tooling. There is also support for Angular JS but the primary focus is Angular (2).