# Why can't this lambda expression auto cast / hot box to a Supplier?

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8, supplier

While calling a function who's has a parameter being `Supplier<O>`... and inputting *lambdas* as need. I had the following error apply and preventing the ide (eclipse-oxygen) from building the project

`Internal compiler error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no glb for [public abstract class java.lang.Number`

The *parent* method similar to

```
Foo foo1;
Foo foo2;

public < O > O run( Function< Foo, O > func ){
    if( func == null )
        return null;
    return firstNotNull( () -> func.apply( foo1 ),
                         () -> func.apply( foo2 ) );
}
```

and the *child* method:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static final < O > O firstNotNull( Supplier< O >... funcs ){
    for( Supplier< O > func : funcs ){
        O obj = func.get();
        if( obj != null )
            return obj;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Going back to the error given, The class Number not mentioned in the class; yet a core java class was giving errors on compile.

However, when editing the *parent* to

```
public < O > O run( Function< Foo, O > func ){
    if( func == null )
        return null;
    return firstNotNull( (Supplier< O >) () -> func.apply( foo1 ),
                         (Supplier< O >) () -> func.apply( foo2 ) );
}
```

The `error` no longer occurs and the IDE successfully builds and complies. I'm making this post as I could not find a similar post online other than suggesting deleting broken builders from eclipse, which does not work on this variant of the issue; thus I'm logging this help other developers with a similar problem.

I also asking to find out what mistake is occurring and why it happens?

**P.S.** I notice this only became an issue after java updated to `8.0_151` from `8.0_144`.

**Update:**

I've changed the java version from 8u151 to 8u152 and tried 9, the error is still present in that workspace. However, I made a new project in eclipse to recreate the error, I was unsuccessful, even if I change java versions. Conclusion: eclipse seems to throw the Error, both Java Builder and Spring Project Builder throw the same error.

Comment: Obviously a bug in the compiler, as indicated by the error text "**Internal compiler error**". Report the bug.

Comment: If this were me, I would try to compile from command line without the IDE, using version `8.0_151`. Also, as of this moment there is also `8.0_152` available. Not that you need to compare output from 3 different versions...

Comment: The error `"no glb for ..."` could possibly be raised by Eclipse, but I cannot reproduce using the given code snippets. First, its not clear what you mean by *super parent* and *child*, but I assume this just relates to the call hierarchy(?) and I placed both methods in the same class. Second, identifiers foo1, foo2 are undeclared. If I add method parameters of this name and invent an empty class Foo, then the program is  happily accepted by javac & ecj. Thirdly, if chasing a bug in Eclipse, please tell us the version(s) you tried.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann - First point - use I was referring to the call hierarchy when I was labeling them super and child, I'll try to be more clear about it. Second: foo1 and foo2 were class fields; I've added them to the code snippets. Third: eclipse - Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) Build id: 20171005-1200

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce the problem with Eclipse 4.7.1a. You may want to check if [4.7.1a was incomplete installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46738339/4611488). Otherwise a complete zip of the project showing the error might help finding the cause (attach it to a new bug report at https://bugs.eclipse.org).